# The angle between the del operator and electric/magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

If the divergence of the electric field is equal to $\frac{p}{ε}$, it must equal to |$\nabla$||E|cos($\theta$) where $\theta$ is the angle between the electric field and the del operator. Same thing goes for the curl of the electric field which is equal to $-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$ or |$\nabla$||E|sin($\theta$). This means the curl of the electric field divided by the divergence of the electric field must be equal to tan($\theta$).

$-\frac{\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}}{\frac{p}{ε}}$ = tan($\theta$)

$\theta$ = arctan($-\frac{\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}}{\frac{p}{ε}}$) = arctan($-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}*\frac{\epsilon}{p}$)

Does this mean anything?

How could there be an angle between the electric field and the nabla if nabla isn't a vector field but an operator?

(same question goes for the angle between the magnetic field and the nabla(which is $\frac{\pi} {2}$))

Comment: *How could there be an angle…?* There isn’t. That way of thinking about dot products and cross products doesn’t apply when there are operators involved. Your “must…” statement is a false premise.

Comment: As an answer above noted, the notation $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}$ is just shorthand. The technically correct notation is $div(\vec{E})$, for divergence. In the shorthand notation, the dot symbol does not actually imply a dot product.

Answer (score 0):

> How could there be an angle between the electric field and the nabla if nabla isn't a vector field but an operator?

i.e. you kinda already know that what you are writing down is nonsense.

When we write $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E$ and $\vec\nabla\times\vec E$, the mathematicians would complain that these are abuses of notation. They are correct; these are incredibly helpful and simple ways to write things, but physicists understand that a naïve reading of these things will run into contradictions, as you currently found.

If you insist upon fixing that, sure, the fact that $\vec\nabla$ is an operator, means that if it is even going to have a direction, that direction will depend upon what particularly it is differentiating. In this case, you have to tell $\vec\nabla$ that it is differentiating $\vec E$, before there is a possible vector output to talk about, and then you can talk about the angles involved. Prior to that, the $\vec\nabla$ operator has no direction to speak of.